# how to code a variable subscripted with another subscripted variable

Tags: subscripts

My first day with Tex and my first stumble ...

How do I code `x` subscripted with `i` subscripted with `n`? `x_i_n` gets rejected:

```
 ! Double subscript
```

That is exactly what I am trying to say ;-) A ref to a good tutorial that would answer this kind of questions would be much appreciated. I saw a dozen but all do not go beyond general article structure and a few examples.

Comment: `x_{i_{n}}` is the way to go.

Comment: note that the official latex syntax always uses braces to avoid such ambiguity, while `x_i` does work you will not see such syntax in the latex book, only `x_{i}` then it is clearer that the syntax you need is `x_{i_{n}}`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other comments, the solution is

```
x_{i_{n}}
```

A good introduction which may fit your interests is [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) by Tobias Oetiker.